# Tryton debug on eclipse

Tags: tryton

I tried to debug trytond/bin/trytond with trytond.conf as configuration.
I used eclipse with pydev.
when i run the localhost:8000 I get this error message:

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Answer (score 0):

You must download the tryton client for your version from:

http://www.tryton.org/download.html

And connect to the tryton server running on localhost:8000

Comment: Web client is still in development, you can find some notes (in spanish) to install it on http://wiki.tryton-erp.es/SAO